# VS2010 Multithreading for a function using _beginthread

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a function written in `C` by `VS2010 Prof`, which reads 1 data file(from 1000 data files), do some analysis and writes some data files in another directory, then continues reading and writing to the end.

Generally my function looks like

```
myfunc(int start_index_fofile,int end_index_offile,char *read_file_directory).
```

To improve the runtimes I created 5 threads using `_beginthread` each of which calls  `myfunc` as follows:

```
thread 1: myfunc(1,200,read_directory)
thread 1: myfunc(201,400,read_directory)
thread 1: myfunc(401,600,read_directory)
thread 1: myfunc(6011,800,read_directory)
thread 1: myfunc(801,1000,read_directory)
```

myfunc works very well over 1000 files and I checked it with `Visual Leak Detector 2.3`, however it shows no memory leak.

As soon as using multithreading, my program gives me access violation. I wrote some small functions and call them in myfunc also I am using `CLAPACK` (32bit release version) and fftw3f. I am totally confused!!! what is the reason? how I can fix it any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell with no code. These threads don't happen to share some resource perhaps ?

Comment: In myfunc there is a function which reads some parameters from a txt file so I used:  WaitForSingleObject(ghMutex, INFINITE);
  Param=ReadTestPara(base_path);
     ReleaseMutex(ghMutex);